# How do i take a argument from the user in Python with a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

For example the user types !set_channel abc how do i get abc from the client and set it as a varible ive looked around but cant seems to find a solution in python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use abc as an input from the discord command.

```
@client.command()
async def set_channel(ctx, variable):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know that the user has typed `!set_channel`, I'm assuming that means you have the whole message.  If so, you can just use the `split()` method and take the second element, like so.

```
message = "!set_channel abc" # Replace with a function call that gets the discord message
argument = message.split(" ")[1] # Will get "abc".  We use 1 as the index because 0 is for the first element
```

The split method will take a string and "split" it into a bunch of other string by what is separated by the string passed in to the method.  We passed in a space `" "`, and the message is `!set_channel abc`.  So when we call `message.split(" ")` it returns `["!set_channel", "abc"]` and when we use index 1 we get the "abc" part of it.